# Wiremock test and pagination production

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, resttemplate, wiremock

I couldn't find answer on my question, maybe is interesting one.
I have in my production code feignClient which asks another server about information by pageable - pageSize(0, 1, 2... etc) by 100 elements. It's working))
But then I tried to test my code by wireMock, I mocked response from pagination and my test died in the cycle. I can't understand the best way to make integration test or my production code is bad.
Parts:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
List<Answer> convertedObjects;
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(0, 100);

do {
page.next();

List<Object> list = FeignClient.answer(page.pageNumber(), page.pageSize());

convertedObjects = converterList(list, Object.class);
objects.addAll(convertedObjects);
} while(!convertedObject.isEmpty());
```

Then I test it

```
Wiremock.stubFor(url).willReturn(object)...
restTemplate.exchange(url)...
```

So this cycle in my production code don't let move on the next step. Because wireMock every time is answering on my willReturn.
Actually I need return only one time, how can deal with it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any additional query parameters or anything that differentiates the first request from the second request? You could use priority to have two separate stubs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Scenarios feature is for.

You'll need to put both stubs into a scenario (i.e. same scenario name), make the first stub trigger a transition to a new state, then make the second stub contingent on the scenario being in the second state and the first stub contingent on the scenario being in the STARTED state.

See: http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/